# Multiple NIC in Azure ARM VM, not found multiple network in the VM though

Tags: azure, vpn, nic

Follow multiple guides, (e.g. http://azureblogger.com/2016/02/create-vnet-with-2-subnets-and-place-vm-with-2-nics-using-arm-powershell/) created a multi-nic VM through ARM powershell. The VM shows multiple nic in azure portal,
[image]

However, in the VM only able to see one network adapter,
[image]

[image]
Am I missing something to configure? My goal is really have a VM with two nic, so I can have the VPN flow through one network adapter, with the other adapter do the regular internet connection so I can access my company internal network even on my client site (client firewall blocks vpn access)

Much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the second NIC to a running VM with a single NIC? If so this is not supported. The portal will be fixed to block this scenario.